# How to create the seeds for invoking spl cpi instruction?

Tags: solana-program, spl-token, anchor-lang, spl-associated-token-account, anchor-spl

I need a program owned token account to hold WSOL. I am creating it like thus

```
   #[derive(Accounts)]                                                 
   pub struct InitializeProgramTokenAccount<'info> {                     
       ///CHECK: only read from, address checked in function                                                                                                                                             
       pub authority_pda: UncheckedAccount<'info>,                                                                                                                 
       #[account(                                                                                                                                                  
           init,                                                                                                                                                   
           payer = payer,                                                                                                                                          
           token::mint = mint,                                                                                                                                     
           token::authority = authority_pda,                                                                                                                       
       )]                                                                                                                                                          
       pub token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,                                                                                                            
       pub mint: Account<'info, Mint>,                                                                                                                             
       #[account(mut)]                                                                                                                                             
       pub payer: Signer<'info>,                                                                                                                                   
       pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,                                                                                                                 
       pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,                                                                                                                   
       pub associated_token_program: Program<'info, AssociatedToken>,                                                                                              
       pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
  }
```

The authority_pda address is found using

```
let (auth_pk, bump) = Pubkey::find_program_address(&[AUTH_SEED.as_bytes().as_ref()], &crate::ID);
```

I am trying to do transfer, create_account, close_account using anchor spl_token cpis. Eg:

```
   let seeds = &[AUTH_SEED.as_bytes().as_ref(), &[bump]];
   let program_unwrap_wsol_context = CpiContext::new(
       ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
       anchor_spl::token::CloseAccount {
           account: ctx.accounts.program_wsol_account.to_account_info(),
           destination: ctx.accounts.pda_authority.to_account_info(),
           authority: ctx.accounts.pda_authority.to_account_info(),
       }
   );
   anchor_spl::token::close_account(program_unwrap_wsol_context.with_signer(&[seeds]))?;
```

When I pass in seeds as &[AUTH_SEED.as_bytes().as_ref(), [bump]], I get the error

```
> Instruction references an unknown account ....
> > Program returned error: An account required by the instruction is missing
```

If I pass in the seeds as &[AUTH_SEED.as_bytes().as_ref()] then I get the error

```
> > Program returned error: Could not create program address with signer seeds provided seeds do not result in a valid address
```

I assume this is because I am not using the off-the-shelf token::authority?

How to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this.

`anchor_spl::token::close_account(program_unwrap_wsol_context.with_signer(&[&seeds[..]))?;`